Пайтон не полностью копирует HTML текст страницы
При попытке получить HTML со странички сайта, информация получается не вся
import requests

response = requests.get('ссылка_на_сайт')
file = open('text.txt', 'a')
try:
    doc = response.content.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
except:
    doc = response.content.decode('cp1251', errors='ignore')
file.write(doc)

Код запускается, записывает информацию в txt файл, но при сравнении HTML с браузера и того что записалось в файл сильно отличается тем что части кода отсутствует. Как это можно исправить?

Скорее всего страница формируется JS скриптами, тут только через Selenium браузер эмулировать. Но может и состав передаваемых хедеров влияет.
